# Handle exceptions returned by parallel query server

Tags: exception, plsql, parallel-processing, oracle11g

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle exceptions in PL/SQL when the error is returned by a parallel query server.

Consider the following :

```
BEGIN                   

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('ALTER <SOME_INDEX> REBUILD PARALLEL(4) );

EXCEPTION

    WHEN OTHERS THEN

    IF SQLCODE = -01652 THEN

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not enought space');

    ELSE

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('[SQLCODE] -> '||SQLERRM);
        NULL;

    END IF;

END;
```

I'm trying to handle ORA-01652 to notify that the tablespace is full.

The problem here is that I don't catch :

`ORA-01652 unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace <TBS>`

but rather :

`ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P001`

So ORA-01652 isn't stored in SQLCODE. How could I handle the real exception here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trap the error (a rare case in which WHEN OTHERS is required) and use DBMS_Utility.Format_Error_Stack to read the underlying error.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_util.htm#sthref9680

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that's not excactly what I need. I added DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK); and it returns both exceptions alright, but what I need is to test the error code of the 2nd exception to print a message when it is an ORA-01652. How can I do that using this method?

Comment: I expect that you'll have to parse the return value of Format_Error_Stack.

Comment: Oh I see, like decomposing the returned string to analyse the different error codes inside using string manipulation functions right? If that's what you mean, I'll need to learn how to do that first! :)

Comment: Yep, that sounds like the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, problem solved using David Aldridge's pieces of advice. If someone's having a similar problem, here's the solution I came up with, using the INSTR function :

```
BEGIN                   

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('ALTER <SOME_INDEX> REBUILD PARALLEL (DEGREE 4));

EXCEPTION

    WHEN OTHERS THEN

        -- If the error_stack contains the error code, then the error obviously occured
        -- INSTR will return the position of the string we are looking for
        -- otherwise, it will just return 0, hence the search condition :

        IF INSTR(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK,'ORA-01658') > 0 THEN

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Tablespace full, too bad!');

        ELSE

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR : '||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);

        END IF;

END;
```